# On logging into my web page, I want my div to transition and remain at the transition size

Tags: html, css

how, please help..I can only transistion on hover.

```css
.line
    {
    background:#ff0000;
    height:10px;
    width:50px;
    transition:width 3s;
    margin-left:4px;
}
.line:hover
{
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"> </div>
```

I want to transition on login to the webpage...without hovering on my div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
    document.querySelector('.line').style.width = '300px';
});
```

```css
.line
    {
    background:#ff0000;
    height:10px;
    width:50px;
    transition:width 3s;
    margin-left:4px;
}
.line:hover
{
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"> </div>
```

Use javascript to trigger the width as the page is first loaded.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `@keyframes`-

```css
.line
    {
    background:#ff0000;
    height:10px;
    width:50px;
    animation: expand 3s forwards; // 'forwards' will keep ending state of animation
    margin-left:4px;
}

@keyframes expand {
  to { width: 300px }
}
```

```html
<div class="line"> </div>
```

Comment: okay..Thanks...that worked..but I want it to remain at 300px....not to go back to it's original size

Comment: @DemiladeSamuel I've edited the answer

Comment: ya great job forwards is the way to fix it  :)

Comment: okay..Thanks..Fixed!